# Как отправить данные из html файла в файл JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим есть html страница, на ней есть элемент input, к html странице подключен js файл, в котором я хочу получить текст введенный в input, каким образом это можно сделать? Если коротко: алгоритм взаимодействия html и javascript?

Comment: Кури `DOM в javascript`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Алгоритм:***

1. Находите JavaScript-ом на странице нужный `input`

---

**UPD** (*из комментариев @Grundy*)

> Чем искать:
>
> - [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
> - [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
> - [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)
> - [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)
> - [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
> - [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

---

2. Считываете его значение

***Пример:***

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input"),
    output = document.getElementById("out");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  out.innerText = input.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="input" />

<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Чем искать: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName), [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо - добавил в ответ